# using libpurple from .NET

Tags: .net, instant-messaging, libpurple

Can someone direct me to a code sample of how to use libpurple from .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libpurple is an unmanaged library - you'll need to either obtain a wrapper for it, or write your own.  Quick Google search did not reveal any good .Net wrappers so writing your own might be your only option.

Here's a simple tutorial on writing a wrapper: [Call Unmanaged Code. Part 1 - Simple DLLImport](http://www.csharphelp.com/archives/archive52.html)

Comment: Looks like it's non-trivial: http://www.nabble.com/Re:-Porting-libpurple-to-C--p17551207.html Somebody started a project but apparently never uploaded anything: http://code.google.com/p/libpurple-sharp/

Comment: Yeah, I saw those.  It's a shame too, as this would be a very useful wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

There is LibPurple-Sharp project https://code.google.com/p/libpurple-sharp/